# Landing page for guests using codigniter and facebook authentication

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

I'm currently setting up a new website which uses facebook authentication to log in users. I'm wondering how I would go about showing a landing page for unauthenticated users using codeigniter. I'm using the javascript api. I already have the authentication set up, but I don't think a redirect is the way to go. Currently it's just a single page which asks for a log in if you're not logged in. I want a facebook.com style authentication method where the users is prompted with an unauthenticated landing page (without redirect) and another page when a user IS authenticated. Any ideas?

I'm using the facebook javascript API

Answer (score 0):

> I want a facebook.com style authentication method where the users is prompted with an unauthenticated landing page (without redirect) and another page when a user IS authenticated. Any ideas?

Simply bring the “landing page”, which from your description I’d rather assume is an in-page modal dialog, to show up with JS after you have made the decision that the visitor is not logged in in any way or form.

Whether you have that dialog as an HTML element, which is initially hidden, embedded directly into your page, or generate it on–the–fly via JavaScript … those details are up to you.

Comment: I could indeed just load the page with jquery. Would that be **the** way to go?